# how to remove time from date in C# for loop

Tags: c#, datetime

```
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    @Html.Raw(Helper.FormatData.(row["DATE"].ToString().Trim(),null,true))}
```

The results I get is `03/07/2015 12:00 am`
what i like to get is `2015/03/07` year month day or month day year if the first option is not possible. 
Thank you

Here is the full code

```
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData.Tables[0].Rows){                       
    string newDate = "";
    if(TabData.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
    {                           
        if(row["SAVEDATE"].ToString().Trim() != "3/1/2017 12:00:00 AM")
        {
            newDate = ((DateTime)row["SAVEDATE"]).ToString("d");
        }
        else
        { 
            newDate=" Proposed 7/1/2017";
        }
    }   
<tr>
    @Html.Raw(Helper.FormatData(DateTime.Parse(newDate.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Trim(),null,true)) </tr>}
```

so for the rows that the value is "3/1/2017 12:00:00 am " i want to display Proposed date. but for all the other values i want to just get the date. not time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime`s [overload for `ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var stringDate = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Change to:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    @Html.Raw(DateTime.Parse(row["DATE"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

---

I think that if you want to keep the `"Proposed 7/1/2017"` text then parse the date into the correct string format already in the if statement and then jus use it:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData.Tables[0].Rows){                       
    string newDate = "";
    if(TabData.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
    {                           
        newDate = (row["SAVEDATE"].ToString().Trim() != "3/1/2017 12:00:00 AM") ? 
            ((DateTime)row["SAVEDATE"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : 
            " Proposed 7/1/2017";
    }   
<tr>
    @Html.Raw(newDate) </tr>
}
```

Comment: where would i add that code im new to coding sorry :-(

Comment: can you add the full code please. i still get the overload error

Comment: i did get same error as Wizard91 code ( The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 1 )

Comment: @john - Please show the exact string that `row["DATE"]` holds. If I take the one in your question and try to `DateTime.Parse` it it works

Comment: Sorry i  should have posted the whole code but i dindn't want to make it more complicated.

Comment: @john - that fine. but look - if it goes into the else then `newDate=" Proposed 7/1/2017";` which can't be parsed into a `DateTime`...

Comment: thank you for your help. i figure did out check my updated code. thank you

Comment: @john if this answer helped you solve the problem please consider marking it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Since you're utilizing Razor, you could do the following:

```
@Html.Raw(row["Date"].ToShortDateString())
@Html.Raw(row["Data"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Another approach, would be to actually decorate your model in a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to use ToString method overloading with time format parameter:

```
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   DateTime result;
   @Html.Raw(Helper.FormatData(DateTime.TryParse(row["DATE"].ToString(), out result) ? result.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : row["DATE"].ToString().Trim(),null,true))
}
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: My gap, missed that you need to parse date first. I have updated the code.

Comment: i get new error with this one ( The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 1 )

Comment: Which value was not recognized? Could you show me cell value which causes the error? Probably it is NULL or not time value.

Comment: for that particular record that i'm searching there is No NULL values all the rows has dates and all the data type is the same

Comment: @john Sound's like your date field, supports `DBNull`.  Which means you would want:  `if(row["Date"] != DBNull.Value || row["Date"] != null)`

Comment: @john I have changed the code, could you try it. It should fix the issue.

Comment: did you see the full code that i posted above? i did use your updated code i get the following error ( CS0118: 'System.DateTime' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable')

Comment: I figure did out. thanks for your help, Check the my edited code.